# Multiple inheritance, 'need' to extend two classes

Tags: php

Assuming we have two classes, in the `\Base\Form\` namespace:

```
class Field {
    protected $name;
    protected $value;
}

class DropdownField extends Field {
    protected $options = [];
    // with functions like setOptions(), addOption(), removeOption() etc.
}
```

Now, in another namespace, a class exists that extends on `Field`, that has an additional `'layout_position'` property:

```
namespace Integrations;
class IntegrationsField extends \Base\Form\Field {
    const LAYOUT_POSITION_LEFT  = 'left';
    const LAYOUT_POSITION_RIGHT = 'right';
    protected $layoutPosition = self::LAYOUT_POSITION_LEFT;
}
```

Now, you might see this one coming, but in the event of an `IntegrationsField` that can also be a dropdown:

```
namespace Integrations;
class IntegrationsDropdownField extends \Base\Form\DropdownField {}
```

Of course, this one should also have the `$layoutPosition`, that should be inherited from `IntegrationsField`, but since we can't extend two classes, what is the best solution to go for here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP doesn't support multiple inheritence. You can however rewrite your logic using traits to (sort of) simulate it.

```
class Field {
    protected $name;
    protected $value;
}

trait Dropdown {
    protected $options = [];
    // with functions like setOptions(), addOption(), removeOption() etc.
}

interface IntegrationPositions { 
    const LAYOUT_POSITION_LEFT  = 'left';
    const LAYOUT_POSITION_RIGHT = 'right';
}

trait Integration {
    protected $layoutPosition = IntegrationPositions::LAYOUT_POSITION_LEFT;
}

class DropdownField extends Field {
     use Dropdown;
}

class IntegrationField extends Field {
     use Integration;
}

class DropdownIntegrationField extends Field {
     use Integration,Dropdown;
}
```

Update: As @Adambean noted traits cannot have constants. I've therefore updated the example using an enum.

This feels strange to have to declare an enum that's meant to be internal to a trait but PHP does not seem to allow any other mechanism to achieve this as far as I know, I am open to any other ideas.

Comment: This exact example wouldn't work because traits cannot have constants. (This throws a fatal error.)

Comment: @Adambean I've updated the example with an "enum" of some sort. It doesn't sit well with me but it doesn't seem that PHP is giving us much choice in this.

Comment: Interfaces can have constants? I wish I knew that 9 hours ago. :D